# function doesn't work on button (myMove is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick)

Tags: javascript, html, function, vue.js, onclick

This is my html:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="myContainer">
      <div id="nav">
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
        <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      </div>
      <router-view />
      <button onclick="myMove()">Test</button>
      <img id="picture" :src="randomImage" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my function **myMove()** doesn't work on click and i don't understand why, should be an animation(picture should go down from the top) do you have some solution guys?

one more thing, JavaScript:

```
function myMove() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("picture");
  let pos = 0;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

and one more thing, i am using vue-cli
maybe problem is some how connected with that or for example i am using ESlint and everything should be ES6, maybe i didn't use some needed conditions?
Waiting for your answer,thank you!

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: How do the HTML and JS refer to each other? is it one file with JS in the head, or maybe two loose ones with require/import? If you could post an example it would be most helpful

Comment: @Thanthu yes, myMove is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @BillieBobbel it works really easy, just simply in tags <template> <script> <style> they are separate

Comment: You are using Vue.js right ? Have you declared myMove() inside method: ?

Comment: Seems like @Thanthu has a point. https://flaviocopes.com/vue-methods/ seems to suggest declaring the function inside the method. But I have to admit I ain't no Vue.JS expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the **position** property of your `<img>` element to either *relative* or *absolute*.
The default is *static* and will keep your image in place.

```
<img id="picture" :src="randomImage" style="position:relative" />
```